# How do I add a string to Google Firestore snapshot query?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore looks like this: samples => picture1 => {link1: "somelink.jpg", link2: "somelink.jpg" etc.}

Everything is fine when I manually supply the link like so:

```
picRef.onSnapshot(function(doc){
    if (doc && doc.exists){
        const myPicData = doc.data();
somePicture.src = myPicData.link1}}
```

However, I can't get it to work if I do something like:

```
counter = 1;
somePicture.src = myPicData + ".link" + counter;
```

If I console.log it, the link turns into [object%20Object].link1.

How do I fix it? Do I need promises here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to access an element in the object through appending a string, which is not a possible operation in javascript.

For example,

```
   let doc={link1: "somelink.jpg", link2: "somelink.jpg"}
   console.log(doc.link1)         // outputs: somelink.jpg
   console.log(doc + ".link" + 1) // outputs: [object Object].link1
```

meaning that, the string gets appended to the object. The right way to access using a string would be:

```
   console.log(doc ["link" + 1])              // outputs: somelink.jpg
```

In case if you want to assign a default value,

```
   console.log(doc["link" + 3] || "default") // outputs: default
```

Hope I understood right and this helps!

Comment: Yes, this helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate it through ForEach

```
picRef.onSnapshot(function(user){
   user.ForEach(function(data){
    if (data && data.exists){
        const myPicData = data.data();
        counter = 1;
         somePicture.src = myPicData + ".link" + counter;
   })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work for me. It says 'forEach is not a function'.